# Script to do ls after cd

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to make a bash script where every time I execute the `cd` command I get the list of files and folder of the new folder (`ls`).

I found the next bash function to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

cs() { cd "$@" && ls; }
```

I saved it: `~/.scripts/cs`. This worked. I added it to my `PATH`, in `.bash_profile`:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.scripts
export PATH
```

When I execute it like `. .scripts/cs` it works, but when I'm in another window nothing happen. I thought I need to call the function inside the script so I modified it:

```
#!/bin/bash

cs() { cd "$@" && ls; }

cs
```

And now when I execute cs in other windows I just get the correct `ls` command but it doesn't change the directory.

With all I've read, my conclusion is that the cs command is executed in a "subshell" and the cd command is executed there, and in my current shell I'm only receiving the `ls`. I tried doing an alias in my `.bashrc` file:

```
alias cs='. cs'
```

But honestly I don't know what should happen and I'm only getting the following error:

```
bash: /home/ggf/.scripts/cs: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/ggf/.scripts/cs: line 4: `cs() { cd "$@" && ls; }'
```

Any solution or recommendation? Sorry for my bad english I'm from Argentina. Any solution for the last error too? I think it would be useful for another occasion.

Comment: Just put `cs() { cd "$@" && ls; }` in your `.bashrc`. Skip the script file, alias, etc. Note that you will have to open a new terminal to get a clean shell, otherwise it'll remember the alias and try to keep using it.

Comment: This worked perfect! Then I'm forced to keep it in .bashrc? There is no way to separate it into another file? Just curious

Comment: You could put it (and maybe some other function/alias definitions) in another file, and `source` that from `.bashrc`, but you still have to have *something* in `.bashrc` to add the definition to each new shell you open.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - why don't you make the first comment an answer?

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put

```
cs() { cd "$@" && ls; }
```

in your `.bashrc`. Skip the script file, alias, etc. Note that you will have to open a new terminal to get a clean shell, otherwise it'll remember the alias and try to keep using it.

Explanation of why it pretty much has to go in .bashrc: If you put it in a separate file in your `PATH`, then by default that will get run in a subprocess; changes it makes (including changing directory, defining functions and aliases, etc) will be local to that subprocess. There are ways to avoid this, but they all involve either extra typing, or making a change to `.bashrc` (or some other shell startup file):

- You could run that file with `.` or `source`, which involve extra typing every time you use the function. (Note: in this case you wouldn't use a function, just have the file execute `cd "$@" && ls` directly.)
- You could create an alias to `.` or `source` the file, but then you have to modify `.bashrc` to include that alias definition.
- You could put the function (or alias) definition in a file, and load that with `.` or `source`, but this involves extra typing every time you open a shell.
- You could automate that by using `.` or `source` in your `.bashrc`, but now you're modifying .bashrc, and you might as well just put the definition directly there.

  (Exception: some people like to organize their shell startup files into e.g. a file of alias definitions, one of function definitions, another of parameter settings, etc... and then `source` those from `.bashrc` and/or other shell startup files. Some OSes even come with default startup files that support this out of the box. If you find this sort of organization helpful, by all means use it.)

BTW, I sometimes see people create overly complex solutions to problems like this, like having an alias that sources a file that creates a function... IMO unless that complexity is actually doing something useful, lose it. In this case a function can do everything that's needed, so that's all you should use.